# Enable Translation for Record in Typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I'm using Typo3 8.7.24 and want to create an extension which creates news. I managed to create news records in the storage folder but i also want to make them translatable like in the attached screenshot. What do I have to do to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to translate the storage folder. You need to create a record of type "Alternative Page Language" there.

To do so, use the list module and add the record there.

Comment: Thank you! I really forgot to translate the Storage folder.